# Multiple find and replace in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using regular expression in Notepad++ to find and replace `<span class="bold">(.*?)</span>` with `<strong>\1</strong>` and `<span class="italic">(.*?)</span>` with `<i>\1</i>`.  I have to do this to a lot of documents and want to know if I can accomplish both of these using a single find and replace.

Comment: No, at least not realistically..but you should be able to do find/replace in all documents, and then just do it twice.

Comment: Maybe notepad++ is just the wrong tool for this.

Comment: I know notepad++ does "find in files", does it allow "find & replace in files"? Otherwise yeah, probably the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "pages" instead of "documents".  I found the find and replace in files, but don't have a nice collection of files.  I'll work with what I have.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider using [**sed**](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) to accomplish this task using a single command line. The below example will find/replace multiple patterns/replacements in all `.txt` files in a given directory.

```
sed -e 's/pattern1/replacement1/g;s/pattern2/replacement2/g' *.txt
```

To actually replace those patterns, use the `i` option. The `-r` option allows extended regular expressions.

```
sed -i -re 's!<span class="bold">(.*?)</span>!<strong>\1</strong>!g;s!<span class="italic">(.*?)</span>!<i>\1</i>!g' *.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with somewhat of a hack to make this work, however it can only make `<span class="bold">` into `<b>` not `<strong>` because it captures a character from the class:

```
<span class="(b(?=old)|i(?=talic))[^"]+">(.*?)<\/span>
<\1>\2</\1>
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eA7dT6)

---

**Explanation:**

```
<span class="
(             (?# start capture group for new element)
  b           (?# match b...)
  (?=old)     (?# followed by old)
 |            (?# OR)
  i           (?# match i)
  (?=talic)   (?# followed by italic)
)             (?# end capture group)
[^"]+         (?# match non-" characters that were found in lookaheads)
">
(.*?)         (?# lazily capture the contents of the span)
<\/span>
```

---

But you should be able to [find/replace in all files](http://www.phpsuperblog.com/misc/find-and-replace-text-for-multiple-files-with-notepad/) with Notepad++...